# C Problem with injecting EXE into another process

Tags: c, portable-executable

Hi im trying to inject a small .exe which displays a Message box into another process, but everytime I call CreateRemoteThread the Process crashes.
I have seen others use Get/Set Context to execute their exe and tried to do the same thing, except that I tried to use CreateRemoteThread:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bQWRW0VUXR4
CreateRemoteThread does not return an error so Idk what I did wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

char * load(char* File)
{
    FILE * f = fopen(File,"rb");
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_END);
    int x = ftell(f);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    
    char * Buff = malloc(x);
    x = fread(Buff,1,x,f);
    printf("%d Bytes gelesen!",x);
    return Buff;
}
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void* Base = load("Injection.exe");
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER * hDOS = Base;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS * hNT = Base + hDOS->e_lfanew;

    STARTUPINFOA SI;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
    ZeroMemory(&SI,sizeof(SI));
    ZeroMemory(&PI,sizeof(PI));
    
    if (!CreateProcessA("Test.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,0,CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&SI,&PI))
        printf("\n\nERROR CREATING PROCESS: %d",GetLastError());
        HANDLE hProc = PI.hProcess;

    BYTE * ImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(hProc,NULL,hNT->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage,MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    printf("\nAllocated Base: %p",ImageBase);

    int NoS = hNT->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
    int OHSize = hNT->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader;
    printf("\nNumber of Sections: %d",NoS);
    printf("\nSize of Optional Headers %d",OHSize);
  
  
    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER * SEC = (hDOS->e_lfanew + Base + sizeof(IMAGE_FILE_HEADER) + 4 + hNT->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader);
    for (int i = 0; i <= NoS; i++)
    {
        printf("\nSECTION NUMBER: %d NAME: %s",i,SEC[i].Name);
        SIZE_T BW;
        if (0 == WriteProcessMemory(hProc,(ImageBase+SEC[i].VirtualAddress),(Base+ SEC[i].PointerToRawData),SEC[i].SizeOfRawData,&BW))
            printf("\nERROR WRITING SECTION: %d",GetLastError());
        else 
            printf("  SIZE: %d  WRITTEN: %d",SEC[i].SizeOfRawData,BW);
            
    }
    


    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE TA = (hNT->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint + ImageBase);
    DWORD TID = 0;

    if (NULL == CreateRemoteThread(hProc,NULL,0,TA,NULL,0,&TID)) 
        printf("\n\nERROR CREATING THREAD : %d",GetLastError());
    else 
        printf("\n\nSUCESS CREATING THREAD");
    
    getchar();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: Could it be that I need to do base Relocation first? I watched the video again and that guys code only reserves memory at the preferred base adress and doesnt even retry when that is not possible, my code directly lets the OS choose the location.

Comment: Might wanna check if fopen was successful. Also, you leave the file open in read-only mode. You should probably fclose before leaving the load function.